# Is it possible to query Field and get main collection field and get sub collection with sub collection documents on cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query fields and get all sub-collections and fields. Is it possible?

[image]

```
      Stream<List<ChatFieldModel>> getChatField(String uid) {
        var ref = _db.collection('chats')
             .where('toUserId', isEqualTo: uid);
//Afterthat need to get sub collection with sub collection list of documents and main collection fields value. is it possible?

        return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.documents
            .map((doc) => ChatFieldModel.fromForestore(doc))
            .toList());
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries are shallow. They only return documents from the collection that is (or, if you use collection group queries, the collections that are) being queried.

So if you're querying `chats`, you will only get documents from that collection. To load documents from the `messages` subcollection you will need to perform an additional query/read operation.