# Performing a CRUD function to a sub-collection for Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to execute a CRUD functions on my web application.

- When a user registered to the application, it automatically stored in a collection called users
- In the Users Document, a **unique ID** is generated by Firebase. To represent each unique users.
- Within each unique ID, there's a sub-collection of **profile** and **orders**.

[image: Firestore's Structure]

Right now I am trying to create a delete function that is able to delete the fields in the sub-collection profile.

From what I understand, you need to create a proper path to access that information in the sub-collection as such;

```
db.collection( ).doc( ).collection( ).doc( )
```

I have managed to do so:

```
deleteUser(id){

          if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {

            db.collection('users').doc('GO6xtaokljhjLFMGSOPj').collection('profile').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
                console.log(id);
                console.log("Document deleted!");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
          }
        }
    },
```

The way I am getting the sub-collection **id** is by embedding the doc.id to a key to differentiate each unique profile from different users:

```
created() {
        db.collectionGroup('profile').onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
            this.Users = [];
            snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {
                this.Users.push({
                    key: doc.id,
                    fname: doc.data().fname,
                    lname: doc.data().lname,
                    username: doc.data().username,
                    mail: doc.data().mail,
                    phone: doc.data().phone,
                    adress: doc.data().adress,
                })
            });
        })
    },
```

..and then sending this key to a delete function:

```
<tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in Users" :key="user.key">
                    <td>{{ user.fname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.lname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.mail }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.adress }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <router-link :to="{name: 'Edit', params: { id: user.key }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit
                        </router-link>
                        <button @click.prevent="deleteUser(user.key)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

The problem that I am currently facing is that, every-time I want to delete a different profile, It require me to hardcode the path:

[Generated ID that required hardcoding to access each sub-collection of Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esqCR.png)

```
 db.collection('users').doc('GO6xtaokljhjLFMGSOPj').collection('profile').doc(id)
```

Is there a solution that doesn't require me to hardcode the **unique ID** of Users every time I want to perform a CRUD Functions or is this an example of how not to design a firestore? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**EDITED: 5/10/2020**

Based on GitHub: https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase/issues/7#issuecomment-492877986

It seems to me that what I am trying to achieve is not possible at the moment? Can anyone clarify? Do I need to redo the structure of the Firestore completely?

**EDITED: 9/10/2020**

Based on: [Is it possible to query Field and get main collection field and get sub collection with sub collection documents on cloud firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223070/is-it-possible-to-query-field-and-get-main-collection-field-and-get-sub-collecti)

**EDITED: 15/10/2020**

[Web Application View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9rUe.png)

Comment: to get to the subcollection the document id is needed, but before that how are you determining the document you need to delete? is this an input from a user or is a document that matched a query you did?

Comment: @JoséSoní  In the web application, I have embedded a delete button for each sub-collection _I will insert a picture of the table in a minute_ . At the moment, I can only delete the sub-collection by hardcoding the the path: `db.collection('users').doc('GO6xtaokljhjLFMGSOPj').collection('profile').doc(id)` , If i want to delete another sub-collection I have to change this `db.collection('users').doc('CHANGE_THIS').collection('profile').doc(id)`. Is there anyway for me to automatically get that document ID?

Comment: is each user on  the image the document you want to change on this query?

Comment: @JoséSoní yes, the table will be automatically updated as new users registered into the application